coproduct(free product) of algebras is free iff both factors are free algebra?
Coproduct of associative algebra is defined in wiki， let us work on field so that coproduct exist generally. And for free algebra I mean semigroup ring generated by semi free groups on $n$ alphabet over field(or tensor algebra on $n$ dimension vector space with chosen basis). Note that we demand finite generators. For consistent, base field is free algebra on zero generator.
Statement: Now if given two $k$-algebra,  their coproduct is free algebra, then are these two algebras must be free algebra?
I think this is some kind cancellation problem. I don't know how to prove this statement(Or how to give a counterexample).  I think minimal free presentation of free algebra (in analogy with polynomial algebra) may help in graded cases.

What do you mean by the converse? I think it's pretty easy to see that a free product of free algebras is free, no?

@tomasz what you say is what I mean forward direction , but if given two algebras, their coproduct is free algebra, how to show they are both free algebra is not obvious to me.

Yeah, that is not so obvious (in fact, I'm not even convinced this is true). Anyway, you should add this clarification to the question.

Not directly an answer, but still relevant:
The converse is at least not true for commutative algebras in positive characteristic. Let $k$ be a field of positive characteristic. As shown by Gupta in [1], there exists a commutative $k$-algebra $A$ (of dimension 3) with the following properties:

$A \not \cong k[x,y,z]$
$A \otimes_k k[w] \cong k[x,y,z,w]$

So here the coproduct is free, but one of the factors is not. This is the celebrated counterexample to Zariski cancellation in positive characteristic. Gupta also generalized this example [2] a bit later.

The question of whether, if the free product $k[t]\ast R$ is a free algebra, then $R$ is also a free algebra, seems to have been open when the paper A cancellation conjecture for free associative algebras by Drensky and Yu was published in 2008.
I did a quick search, but didn't find any indication that the problem has been solved subsequently. But even if it has, it's presumably a hard problem.
